# Compound particles: ni wa

Tags: grammar, particles

So I have this sentence: Sotsugyou paatii ni wa sanka shinai yotei desu.

Now if I take wa from the sentence, it should still mean the same. What is the purpose of wa in this sentence?

Comment: One of the basic functions of this site is that whenever someone asks a question that has already been discussed, we can point that person directly to the original discussion by marking their post as duplicate. Your inhability and/or unwillingness to learn at least hiragana and katakana makes it hard for us to help you, because it is not practical nor advisable to reanswer questions that have already been asked and solved before.